# Help with math symbols in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, symbols

I am writing a PhD thesis using LaTeX. Every thing is going fine, but I have problem with the output of the mathematical symbols in the references lists. I copy one example from the Pdf file to make it clear for you. You can see that the fraction remains the same.

> [1] Mezzacapo, F. and Cirac, J. I. (2010) Ground-state properties of
>   the spin-`\frac{1}{2}` antiferromagnetic Heisenberg model on the
>   triangular lattice: a variational study based on entangled-plaquette
>   states. New. J. Phys., 12,
>   103039.

You can see below the all the packages I use:

```
\documentclass[12pt,PhD,twoside,a4paper]{GB_muthesis}%[10pt,PhD, singlespace]
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,
urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbers,comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{GE_manthesis}
\usepackage{GB_thesis}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{subfigure}% allow subfigures
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{url, enumitem}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{notoccite}%This package is for ingnoring the citation in the caption of the figures and tables.
\begin{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx, you can use the `''` and `{}` buttons to format your question.  See the edit I just made.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please post that entry in the `.bib` file that you are using. It looks as if it is entered as `\verb|\frac{1}{2}|`

Answer (score 18):

With the following MWE you can see how to include mathematical symbols in your bibliography. 
Off course you have to include mathematics with `$`.

The MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}        % loading package filecontents
% writing file \jobname.bib, for example mb-bibtex.bib.
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Mathetitle,
  author  = {Mezzacapo, F. and Cirac, J. I.},
  title   = {Ground-state properties of the spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ antiferromagnetic {Heisenberg} 
             model on the triangular lattice: a variational study based on 
             entangled-plaquette states.},
  year    = {2010},
  journal = {New. J. Phys.},
  number  = {12},
  issn    = {103039},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}         % bibliography style
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}    % better urls in bibliography

\begin{document}
Test of bibliography: 
A title with mathematics~\cite{Mathetitle}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}  % needs package natbib
\bibliography{\jobname}       % uses \jobname.bib, according to \jobname.tex
\end{document}
```

gives you

[image]

Comment: You should probably put _Heisenberg_ in braces to preserve the capital letter as well.