# Deleted Main.bib using filecontents while trying to enter citation involving mathematical treatment

Tags: math-mode, bibliographies, filecontents

Ok. I feel pretty stupid but I was trying to find a solution to using mathematics in bibliography. I ended up using the following example in this forum that used filecontents. 
[Help with math symbols in BibTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108286/help-with-math-symbols-in-bibtex)
The following is what I used right before defining documentclass and database.bib was my main bibliography file in the same folder.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}        % loading package filecontents
% writing file \jobname.bib, for example mb-bibtex.bib.
\begin{filecontents*}{\database.bib}
@ARTICLE{UCH86,
AUTHOR =            {Uchida, I. and Nishina, T. and Mugikura, Y. and Itaya, K.},
TITLE =             {Gas electrode reactions in molten carbonate media. Part I. Exchange current density of oxygen reduction in $(Li+K)CO_3$ eutectic at $650^{\circ}$ C},
JOURNAL =       {J of Electroanal. Chem.},
VOLUME =            {206},
YEAR =              {1986},
PAGES =             {229--239}
}
\end{filecontents*}
```

Unfortunately, database.bib was my most updated bibliography file and it seems to me that putting the above filecontents section before my main .tex (as below) and executing my .tex file wiped out contents of my database.bib leaving just one entry. Is there any way to recover the wiped out file?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{table}
\usepackage[abs]{overpic}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage[version = 3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nomentbl}
\usepackage{thesisdef}
\usepackage{xthesis} %DAL Thesis Style
\usepackage{xtocinc} %Include Table of Contents as the first entry in TOC
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}
\newcolumntype{S}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.8cm}}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}

stuff

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\database} %%% ... Good for using one single database...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Only ever backup data you mind losing. Restore from backup. See if there is an auto-saved version. (E.g. on unix-like systems, look for `.database...`, `database.bib~`. `tmp`, `swp` etc. are possible suffixes. This is editor/system/config dependent.) But if you did what you said, you overwrote the file in place. It is very unlikely you can get anything back unless you are prepared to pay for recovery and even then probably unlikely. (The new file is shorter so may not have overwritten all of the content. However, if you've been using the disk since, it is even less likely.)

Comment: If this was only you most current version, just go back to the next most recent and redo whatever changes you made recently. That is likely to be by far more effective than anything else.

Comment: Using the starred `filecontents*` version overwrites whenever the file already exists.

Comment: Ouch.  For future reference/use: a good combination with the `filecontents` environment is the macro `\jobname`, which expands to the name of the current file the `filecontents` is embedded in.  That way there is less risk you will overwrite a previously existing file with the same extension.  As for file recovery, methods vary depending on many factors, especially OS and its file system (which is a question for another site).

Comment: Sorry for your loss…

Comment: I spent last night trying to recoup my loss of about 25 citations, and it seems now I might be only a little behind. Of course, I had to re-enter about 20 of those. I still need to take care of few remaining. So, it wasn't that bad after all.  Lesson Learnt - Don't be blind.  Funny thing is I never got an inkling of what it was gonna do when I ran that filecontents. So perhaps, can somebody point me to a good method of using mathematics in bibliography. How do you maintain your original .bib file and just be able to write couple of citations that need mathematical treatment.  Thanks

Comment: @Werner What happens when there is no asterisk?

Comment: @jon I don't think I clearly understand the use of \jobname. Do you understand what I was trying to do. Please see my previous comment.

Comment: @ritesh: The [`filecontents` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) makes both `filecontents` and `filecontents*` overwrite files if they already exist. If you don't include the `filecontents` package, these environments still exist, but you won't be able to overwrite the files. From the documentation: "The `filecontents` package provides a hacked-up version of the `filecontents` and `filecontents*` environments that lifts the two restrictions, namely that existing files are never overwritten and that `filecontents` must be used before the `\documentclass` declaration."

Comment: Addendum to @werner `filecontents` adds a comment line, the starred version does not.

Comment: @ritesh -- You can usually load more than one `.bib` file if you need to; e.g., `\bibliography{mainbibliography,addenda}`.  So if you have `database.bib` and a `.bib` file with the same name as the main `.tex` file, you can write: `\bibliography{database,\jobname}`.  Just make sure the entry keys are all unique, and not just unique to each individual file.  And, finally: *backup your `.bib` file!*  Re-entering about 20 entries isn't so bad, but it will soon become nigh impossible....

Comment: @egreg: I know/read that in the documentation. My last comment mentions this fact (perhaps not clear enough).